# How to keep columns from wrapping in HTML?

Tags: html

I am trying to do a layout of cells similar to the output in this picture:

[image: Division Layout]

But I need to do a lot of rows and I want the columns to be a specific size and NOT WRAP to another line if it goes over the size of the screen.  For instance, say I have 10 columns, with each column being 200 pixels.  I want a horizontal scroll if there are too many columns to fit on screen, rather than wrapping the other columns.  My code is something like (I got it off the W3Schools.com website when my first attempt using a table did not work):

```
.column {
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}

<div class="row">
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works great as long as there are not enough columns to go over the size of the screen, but I need it to be wider than the screen (Either that or my final implementation will end up having a bunch of columns set to 2% width of the screen which is going to be ridiculously small).

I have experimented with using "overflow: scroll;" and "display: inline;" but I am not having any success.

For reference, the original project looks like this:

[image: Map Image]

And the coding is all just straight typing into the body, which is extremely difficult to read and edit.

```
<FONT COLOR=CYAN>Star type in angle brackets, &lt; &gt;, means the Star is in The Rift</FONT>
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            | Fuoss      |            |            |            |            |            | Piceance   |            |            |            | Kimberlite |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|            |     <FONT COLOR=MAGENTA>M</FONT>      |            |            |            |            |            |            |            |     <FONT COLOR="#0000FF">H</FONT>      |            |     <FONT COLOR=WHITE>N</FONT>      |     <FONT COLOR=WHITE>N</FONT>      |            |            |     <FONT COLOR=MAGENTA>M</FONT>      |            |            |     <FONT COLOR=MAGENTA>M</FONT>      |     <FONT COLOR=RED>R</FONT>      |            |     <FONT COLOR="#00FF00">A</FONT>      |     <FONT COLOR=MAGENTA>M</FONT>      |            |            |     <FONT COLOR=YELLOW>X</FONT>      |            |            |            |            |            |            |
|            | DowChem    |            |            |            |            |            |            |            | Hewlett-Packard         | Erin       |            |            |            | Elkhorn    |            |            |            | New Jerusalem           | Lyra       |            |            |            | Morgan     |            |            |            |            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your div in a container with the following properties:

```
.container {
    width: max-content;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The div is then exactly as wide as it needs to be (`max-content`) and should scroll if you have more columns than the viewport is wide.

```css
.column {
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
}

.row {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: max-content;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 4</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 4</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 4</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
     <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 4</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Addded the snippet, so you could check out if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was well thought out and extremely helpful.  I had tried using a "container" div, although I had called it "setpage" instead of "container" but I did not know the settings I should be using (I had set width to 3500px, but did not have an overflow setting).

I think my original implementation of the container div may have suffered from the same potential error in the code I had originally copied.  After retyping everything from scratch it all appears to work.  Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the body width to how wide you want it to be.

```
body{width: 3000px}
```

Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: That seems so simple, and I tried using the width setting for the body, I'm not sure why it did not work for me before.  I was using "body {width: 3500; overflow-x: scroll;}" and it was giving me the scrollbar and a 3500px page, but the divs were still wrapping.  I'm wondering if it was another piece in the code that I had gotten that was causing the issue in the first place?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much, I appreciate your time on this!

Comment: Most probably a conflicting bit of code you had somewhere that stopped it working before. That's usually always my issue haha

Answer (score 1):

With a simplification of your HTML, you could use CSS grid:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /* triggering the grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining 10 columns, each of 200px width: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 200px);
  /* defining a 2px gutter between grid-items
     (purely aesthetic, and not required;
     adjust to taste: */
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.cell {
  height: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cell">column 1</div>
  <div class="cell">column 2</div>
  <div class="cell">column 3</div>
  <div class="cell">column 4</div>
  <div class="cell">column 5</div>
  <div class="cell">column 6</div>
  <div class="cell">column 7</div>
  <div class="cell">column 8</div>
  <div class="cell">column 9</div>
  <div class="cell">column 10</div>
  <div class="cell">column 1</div>
  <div class="cell">column 2</div>
  <div class="cell">column 3</div>
  <div class="cell">column 4</div>
  <div class="cell">column 5</div>
  <div class="cell">column 6</div>
  <div class="cell">column 7</div>
  <div class="cell">column 8</div>
  <div class="cell">column 9</div>
  <div class="cell">column 10</div>
  <div class="cell">column 1</div>
  <div class="cell">column 2</div>
  <div class="cell">column 3</div>
  <div class="cell">column 4</div>
  <div class="cell">column 5</div>
  <div class="cell">column 6</div>
  <div class="cell">column 7</div>
  <div class="cell">column 8</div>
  <div class="cell">column 9</div>
  <div class="cell">column 10</div>
  <div class="cell">column 1</div>
  <div class="cell">column 2</div>
  <div class="cell">column 3</div>
  <div class="cell">column 4</div>
  <div class="cell">column 5</div>
  <div class="cell">column 6</div>
  <div class="cell">column 7</div>
  <div class="cell">column 8</div>
  <div class="cell">column 9</div>
  <div class="cell">column 10</div>
  <div class="cell">column 1</div>
  <div class="cell">column 2</div>
  <div class="cell">column 3</div>
  <div class="cell">column 4</div>
  <div class="cell">column 5</div>
  <div class="cell">column 6</div>
  <div class="cell">column 7</div>
  <div class="cell">column 8</div>
  <div class="cell">column 9</div>
  <div class="cell">column 10</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/84ogqp2k/1/).

If you wish to remain with your current HTML layout, then you could still use CSS grid (note that your posted code has only four 'columns,' whereas your question specifies *ten*, so the difference between the ten-column and four-column layout is based purely on that difference):

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/84ogqp2k/2).

You could, of course, also use CSS flex-box layout:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  /* triggers the flexbox layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* this prevents the child elements from wrapping
     to a new line: */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.column {
  /* shorthand for:
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 200px;
   'flex-grow' and 'flex-shrink' define the amount by
   which a given item will grow, or shrink, to fill
   the available space within the parent; 'flex-basis'
   defines the initial size of the flex-item: */
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  /* because we're using the flex-layout for a non-flexible
     layout we're defining both the min-, and max-, width
     to force the element to remain the same size: */
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/84ogqp2k/3).

It's worth noting that, while flex-layout does what we want it to do we're using a deliberately flexible layout mode to define a non-flexible layout in our design; so it's probably better to use either CSS grid or the following:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  /* prevents the child elements from wrapping to new lines: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.column {
  /* allows the elements to be both inline and with a defined
     size (which display: inline wouldn't allow): */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/84ogqp2k/5).

This is the most backwards-compatible approach of those listed, and seems to fit the use-case and requirements.

References:

- "[CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)," - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
- [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)," - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
- [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).